Is there implicit Universal quantification in this definition?
Working on:

Richard Johnsonbaugh. (2018). Discrete Mathematics, 8/e (p. 600)


Definition 12.3.5: Let $G = (N, T, P, \sigma)$ be a grammar.


If $\alpha \to \beta$ is a production and $x\alpha y \in (N \cup T)^{\ast}$, we say that $x\beta y$ is directly derivable from $x\alpha y$ and write $$x\alpha y \Rightarrow x\beta y$$

My question:
Is there an implicit universal quantifier, and are the variables ( \alpha, \beta, x, ) and ( y ) bound by it?
The rough structure would be:
$(\forall \alpha, \beta, x, y)$($\alpha \to \beta \, \text{is a production} \, \wedge ...)$)

Yes, a definition is implicitly universally quantified.
A human is a rational animal will be:

$\forall x[H(x) \leftrightarrow (A(x) \land R(x)]$.

